# Linq query to delete the Child nodes or selected Node on the kendo treeview

Tags: c#, linq, treeview

I have a Treeview displaying all the nodes.The Structure is like 
.P
 .P1
 .P2
 .P3
.B
 .B1
 .B2
  .B21
  .B22
    .B221
    .B222
  .B3
 .C
  .C1
  .C2

And so on.Currently if i try to delete B its getting deleted along with the children on front end. But if i see in the database only B got deleted and childs are present. Below is the query i am Using to delete only the Parent. Can anyone suggest me how to delete the kids by getting the list of all nodes and checking whether it has childs or not and then deleting.Help is needed asap.

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public String removeTree(int id)
    {
           try
            {
                using (var context = new Data.Entities())
                {
                    var delNode = context.Tree.Where(c => c.ID == id).First();
                    if (delNode != null)
                    {
                        context.Tree.Remove(delNode);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.ReturnResult = false;
                        result.ReturnMessage = "Cannot delete.";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                result.ReturnResult = false;
                result.ReturnMessage = exc.Message;
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return JSON.Serialize(result);

        }
```

kendo treeview:

```
  function treeView() {
        var treeMenu = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
        schema: {
            data: function (response) {
                    return JSON.parse(response.d);
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    hasChildren: true,
                    id: "id",
                    children: "HasChildren",
                    hasChildren: "HasChildren",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                        LINK: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                    },
                }
            }
        },
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/getTest",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
            },
           destroy: {
            url: "/Services/Services.asmx/removeTree",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { "id": deleteId }
             },
            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                if ((type == "read") || (type == "update") || (type == "create") || (type == "destroy")) {
                    return JSON.stringify(data);

                } else {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: treeMenu,
        loadOnDemand: false,
        expanded: true,
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataTextField: ['LINK'],
        template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
            }).data("kendoTreeView");}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should look into setting up the foreign key reference from child to parent in your `Tree` table to do Cascading Deletes.

Comment: I am trying to do using a webservice for the delete operations based on the selected node

Comment: Can you show the current definition for your `Tree` table?

Comment: updated with my kendo treeview table structure

Comment: I mean the Table in your DB.  Isn't `context` a `DbContext` that uses EF to connect to a DB?

Comment: Attached image has the table definition

Comment: I assume one of the last two columns is the one that contains the parent id or null if it's the top of the tree.  Now the question is, do you have a foriegn key reference from that column to your ID column?  If not you should create one with `CASCADE DELETE ON` and that will automatically delete the children from the table when you delete a parent.

Comment: Ok that is one scenario if i want to delete a selected child node then what would be the solution

Comment: The only other way is to walk through all the children and delete each one.

Comment: I dont have a foreign key on this table

Comment: Yes but i am not getting the linq query to do that i mean the recursive method to get through all the **childNodes**